# How to expand VHDX that use as physical drive in storage pool?

Tags: windows, storage-spaces

In Windows 10 Storage Spaces, it is possible to create a storage pool that use multiple VHDX as physical drive.  For example, I create and mount 2x 5GB VHDX:

```
PS C:\> New-VHD -Path a:\test.vhdx -SizeBytes 5GB
PS C:\> New-VHD -Path b:\test.vhdx -SizeBytes 5GB
PS C:\> Mount-VHD -Path a:\test.vhdx
PS C:\> Mount-VHD -Path b:\test.vhdx
```

Then, create a storage pool by adding the VHDX as physical disk:

```
# make sure the physical disk is the VHDXs
PS C:\> Get-PhysicalDisk | Where-Object {$_.DeviceId -eq 9 -or $_.DeviceId -eq 10} | select PhysicalLocation

PhysicalLocation
----------------
A:\test.vhdx
B:\test.vhdx


PS C:\> $PhysicalDisks = (Get-PhysicalDisk | Where-Object {$_.DeviceId -eq 9 -or $_.DeviceId -eq 10})

PS C:\> New-StoragePool -FriendlyName "Test" -StorageSubsystemFriendlyName "Windows Storage*" -PhysicalDisks $PhysicalDisks -ResiliencySettingNameDefault Mirror -ProvisioningTypeDefault Thin -Verbose

FriendlyName OperationalStatus HealthStatus IsPrimordial IsReadOnly    Size AllocatedSize
------------ ----------------- ------------ ------------ ----------    ---- -------------
Test         OK                Healthy      False        False      8.97 GB        512 MB
```

The storage pool has 2 utilize two VHDX as physical disks:

```
PS c:\> Get-StoragePool -FriendlyName "Test" | Get-PhysicalDisk

Number FriendlyName           SerialNumber MediaType CanPool OperationalStatus HealthStatus Usage       Size
------ ------------           ------------ --------- ------- ----------------- ------------ -----       ----
9      Microsoft Virtual Disk              SSD       False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 5 GB
10     Microsoft Virtual Disk              SSD       False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 5 GB
```

Next, I expand the VHDXs to 10GB:

```
PS C:\> Resize-VHD -Path a:\test.vhdx -SizeBytes 10GB
PS C:\> Resize-VHD -Path b:\test.vhdx -SizeBytes 10GB
```

But the storage pool size didn't increase:

```
PS C:\> Get-StoragePool -friendlyname Test

FriendlyName OperationalStatus HealthStatus IsPrimordial IsReadOnly    Size AllocatedSize
------------ ----------------- ------------ ------------ ----------    ---- -------------
Test         OK                Healthy      False        False      8.97 GB        512 MB
```

I think the VHDX Storage Pool partition that haven't extend yet.  Is that possible to extend the partition to fully utilize the available space in VHDX?